# Disable AOD animation when update notification in lock screen

Tags: android, kotlin, service, notifications

I have a foreground service with a notification,
the service is active all the time and update notification each 30 seconds even when screen is off,

In some android phones with AMOLED screen, there is an option that **off screen** lights when notification comes.

it's ok when new notification comes in screen off, **BUT** it also lights screen when a notification **updates** its content text,

I dont want off screen lights when service updates content text of notification.

I tried the following and not worked:

1-

```
NotificationChannel#enableLights(false)
NotificationChannel#importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_LOW
```

2- Use the same notificationBuilder and notificationID for updating notification

3-

```
NotificationBuilder#setOnlyAlertOnce(true)
```

4-

```
NotificationChannel(channelID, channelName, NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_LOW)
```

I appreciate if you can tell me a solution for this problem.